# How to take the derivative of $ y = xA^T + b$ w.r.t. $A$ and $b$, where $x,b$ are vectors and $A$ is a matrix

Tags: matrix-calculus

How exactly could I take the derivative of the following expression?

$$ y = xA^T + b$$

Let's say that I have $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$, $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m,n}$, $y \in \mathbb{R}^{m}$, and $b \in \mathbb{R}^{m}$. And, I wish to take the derivative of $y$ with respect to $A$ and $b$, i.e. $\frac{\partial y}{\partial A}$ and $\frac{\partial y}{\partial b}$. I understand that $\frac{\partial y}{\partial A}$ would a rank-3 tensor containing $\frac{\partial y_i}{\partial A_{jk}}$, although I'm not entirely sure how to get to the solution. I've tried looking through the matrix cookbook but the only other solution (that I can find at least) is for $\frac{\partial x^Ta}{\partial x}$ where $x$ and $a$ in this case are both vectors. So, I'm a little confused!

With regards to the second term, $\frac{\partial y}{\partial b}$, I would assume that this is just the identity matrix ($\mathbb{I} \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times m}$) as the terms is just element-wise addition?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\def\E{{\cal E}}\def\p#1#2{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}\def\v#1{\operatorname{vec}(#1)}$Doing
the calculation using index notation (i.e. element-wise) is your best option
$$\eqalign{
y_i &= A_{ij}x_j + b_i \\
\p{y_i}{b_k}
  &= \p{b_i}{b_k}
   = \delta_{ik} \quad\implies \p{b}{b} = I
\\
\p{y_i}{A_{k\ell}}
  &= \p{A_{ij}}{A_{k\ell}}x_j
   = \delta_{ik}\delta_{j\ell}\;x_j
   = \delta_{ik}\,x_\ell 
\\
}$$
You could also [vectorize the equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)#Compatibility_with_Kronecker_products) using Kronecker products
$$\eqalign{
a &\doteq \v{A} \\
y &= (x\otimes I) a + b \\
\p{y}{a} &= (x\otimes I) \p{a}{a} = (x\otimes I) I = (x\otimes I) \\
}$$
Or you could use indexed matrices (sort of a *half-index* notation)
$$\eqalign{
y &= Ax + b \\
\p{y}{A_{jk}} &= \left(\p{A}{A_{jk}}\right)x = E_{jk}\,x \\
}$$
where $E_{jk}$ is a matrix containing all zeros except for a single ${\tt1}$ at the $(j,k)$ element.

Or you can go into *full-tensor* mode by giving a name $(\E)$ to the fourth-order tensor that we encountered using index notation, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
\E_{ijk\ell} &\doteq \delta_{ik}\delta_{j\ell}
\quad\implies\quad
\p{y}{A} &= \E x \\
}$$

Comment: Probably a stupid non-mathematical or practical question: do you know how to implement these tensors in programming languages like matlab or python? thank you in advance.

Comment: @user550103 The simplest way in Matlab is `E = reshape(speye(m*n), m,n,m,n)`  In Julia I sometimes use an array comprehension `E = [1*(i==k)*(j==l) for i=1:m,j=1:n,k=1:m,l=1:n]`  You can do something similar in Python / NumPy.

Comment: Thank you very much, greg. Consequently, I have got one more question. Let us say in Matlab, how to multiply the tensor $\mathcal{E}$ with a vector $x$ to obtain the gradient? I must admit that I am still not able to use and understand tensors much (I really hope that I can understand more by playing practically).

Comment: In Julia I use _Einsum_  which I believe was ported from a NumPy package with the same name. Matlab must have libraries for dealing with tensors, but I'm not familiar with those. You might learn more by writing your own functions -- just reshape the tensors into matrices, do a matrix multiply, and reshape the result back into a tensor.  The only tricky part is specifying the correct dimensions for the reshape commands.

Comment: Thank you so much, greg!! I think I see the concept now.